# React Native transforms with pivot point

Tags: transform, react-native

I want to rotate a `Text` component with an angle of `-90deg`. The component should be rotated from the left corner instead of middle. I am using below codes:

```
render() {
     return (
            <View style = {{flex : 1}}>
                <View style={styles.sidebar}>
                    <Text style={styles.lblSideBar} numberOfLines = {1} >DUMMY TEXT</Text>
                </View>
            </View>);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sidebar : {
    flex : 1,
    flexDirection : 'row',
    alignItems : 'flex-end',
    justifyContent : 'center',
    width : 30,
  },
  lblSideBar : {
      bottom : 20,
      transform : [{rotate : '-90deg'}],
  }
});
```

I want the bottom space of 20px, but as rotation is happening from center(by default) the text is covering the bottom area after rotation. Please suggest how to achieve that?
Also `react-native` needs the support of **`pivotPoint`** or **`anchorPoint`** or **`transformOrigin`** so that this property can be achieved easily.

Comment: I thought about this, and had the following idea. What if we put the Text inside a View, and we rotate that view. And then we position the Text absolute top left of the View.
This worked for me. I'm not sure how to make a working example atm, but maybe someone has time for that and can post an answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just made a `withAnchorPoint` function to make transform working with anchor point easier in react-native. https://github.com/sueLan/react-native-anchor-point.

You can use it like this:

```js
import { withAnchorPoint } from 'react-native-anchor-point';

getTransform = () => {
    let transform = {
        transform: [{ perspective: 400 }, { rotateX: rotateValue }],
    };
    return withAnchorPoint(transform, { x: 0.5, y: 0 }, { width: CARD_WIDTH, height: CARD_HEIGHT });
};
    
<Animated.View style={[styles.blockBlue, this.getTransform()]} />
```

### I also wrote an article for it.
[image]

The following tricky codes are to set the anchor point or called pivot point of a view.

1. translate the view by x, y, z on the x-axis, y-axis, z-axis
2. apply rotation
3. translate the view back by -x, -y, -z on the x-axis, y-axis, z-axis

```js
          translateX: -w / 2
          rotateY
          translateX: w / 2
```

This means setting the anchor point as (0, 0.5). We apply it in the transform style like this

```js
   const transform = {
      transform: [
          {translateX: -w / 2}, 
          rotateY, 
          {translateX: w / 2}
      ]
    }
    return (   
        <Animated.View style={transform}></Animated.View>
    )
  }
```

```js
          translateX: w / 2
          rotateY
          translateX: -w / 2
```

This means setting the anchor point as (1, 0.5)

```js
          translateX: -w / 2
          translateY: -h / 2
          rotateZ
          translateX: w / 2
          translateY: h / 2
```

This means setting the anchor point as (0, 0)

```js
          translateX: w / 2
          translateY: h / 2
          rotateZ
          translateX: -w / 2
          translateX: -h / 2
```

This means setting the anchor point as (1, 1)

In iOS, it is called anchor point. [About the anchorPoint](https://web.archive.org/web/20210802234757/http://ronnqvi.st/about-the-anchorpoint)

```objectivec
layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
```

In Android, it is called pivot point.

```java
  viewToMove.setPivotX(0);
  viewToMove.setPivotY(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
          angle: 0
     }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.progress()
}

progress(){
     intervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {      
         this.setState({angle: this.state.angle +1})   
     }, (1000); // 1000 milliseconds
}



render () {
        const dx = responsiveHeight(9.5);
        const dy = responsiveHeight(9.5);

        const position= {
            transform: [
              {
                translateX: Math.cos((360 - this.state.angle)  * Math.PI / 180) * dx - Math.sin((360 - this.state.angle) * Math.PI / 180) * dy
              },
              {
                translateY:  Math.sin((360 - this.state.angle)  * Math.PI / 180) * dx + Math.cos((360 - this.state.angle) * Math.PI / 180) * dy
              }
            ]
          };

        return(
            <Animated.View style={position}>
                <Text>Text move</Text>
            </Animated.View>

        );
}
```

NOTE: responsiveHeight, responsiveWidth are introduced in
react-native-responsive-dimensions
BackgroundTimer please check here react-native-background-timer
Import some libraries

Answer (score 0):

The follow code maybe helpful,the red view will transform 180 with the pivot point of (0.5,0), like iOS anchorPoint:

```
/**
 * Created by YQB on 16/9/14.
 */
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,View,Animated,Easing} from 'react-native';

var dimensions =  require('Dimensions') ;
var bgHeight = dimensions.get('window').height;
var bgWidth = dimensions.get('window').width;
var viewHeight = 100;

class RotaTest extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            transformView: new Animated.Value(0),
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(this.state.transformView,{toValue:1,duration:1000}).start();
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <View style={layouts.lineLayout}/>
                <Animated.View
                    style={[layouts.bgViewLayout,{transform:[
                        {translateY: -viewHeight/2},
                        {rotateX:this.state.transformView.interpolate({inputRange:[0,1], outputRange:['0deg','180deg']})},
                        {translateY:viewHeight/2}
                    ]}]}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const layouts = StyleSheet.create({
    bgViewLayout:{
        width:bgWidth * 0.3,
        height:viewHeight,
        top: 100,
        left:100,
        backgroundColor:'red'
    },
    lineLayout:{
        width:bgWidth,
        height:0.5,
        top:100,
        backgroundColor:'black'
    }
});
export default RotaTest;
```

Answer (score 0):

[This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/1248) has a solution.

If you're able to use an SVG, in your render method, you can do something like this:

```html
const pointX = 25;
const pointY = 25;
<Svg onLayout={this.onLayout} viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  {/* Rotate about point x y */}
  <G transform={`translate(${pointX}, ${pointY})`}>
    {/* Everything in AnimatedG gets rotated */}
    <AnimatedG style={{
      transform: [
        {
          translateX: -this.state.offset
        },
        {
          rotate: animation.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
          })
        },
        {
          translateX: this.state.offset
        }
      ]
    }}>
      <G transform={`translate(-${pointX}, -${pointY})`}>
        <Path fill={this.props.color} d="M4.295 0A4.233 4.233 0 001.24 1.24l.75.75a3.175 3.175 0 012.243-.932 3.175 3.175 0 012.244.932l.75-.75A4.233 4.233 0 004.295 0z" />
      </G>
    </AnimatedG>
  </G>
</Svg>
```

The `this.state.offset` is a hack for android which behaves differently. The onlayout to set that value looks like this.

```js
onLayout = Platform.OS === 'android'
    ? e => { this.setState({ offset: e.nativeEvent.layout.width / 2 }) }
    : null;
```

Note: using 25 as my x and y would rotate about the center.

The user who posted the solution included [this fully-functional example](https://snack.expo.io/@msand/vengeful-strawberries)

Answer (score 0):

While doing a project I faced an issue when I was trying to rotate an image around a certain point and I was not able to do in react native as you can do that by using css but in react native you cannot use css so I figured out a way .

1. Convert your image into SVG it will be better if you use vector images. (You can do this by using many online tools like or by using an adobe illustrator where you can get SVG code).
2. Then go to this website where you will get your SVG code converted to JSX. I like this website because by using this website you can convert your for react native and react both.
3. Then you can add JSX in your code and run it but before install react-native-svg from here.
4. Then group the whole path or anything in SVG by  where you can do operations according to your choices.

<G transform=”rotate(90, 300 ,300)” >

//here in rotate props are in order of angle to rotate in degree, x and y coordinate around which you want to rotate the image.
……

or operations like

<G transform=”scale(.4, .4) translate(520,0)” >
…..

You can see live example here .

https://snack.expo.io/@ajay19293/rotate-image-around-a-pivot-point-

Answer (score -1):

I had pretty much the same problem. 
Here is how to do it

Even though rotating with a pivot point is not directly supported, you can achieve the same result, with a combination of rotate, transformX and transformY - it's not to hard:

1. Lets say we allready have the coordinates of the pivot point.
   In your case you could hook on the onLayout Event, that gives you x,y,width and height
2. You take the center of the object to rotate. Again, onLayout is your Friend.
3. Now take the x and y difference of both points, and use this handy formula,
   with angle beeing the angle you want to rotate:

   `rad = angle * Math.PI / 180
   transformX(Math.cos(angle) * dx - Math.sin(angle) * dy)
   transformY(Math.sin(angle) * dx + Math.cos(angle) * dy)
   rotate(angle+"deg")`

I leave it as an exercise to the reader to derive above formula :)
Really it's simple trigonometry

Comment: Thank you very very much! But for me, it works with setting translateY only  >.<

Comment: What are `dx` and `dy`?

Comment: "I leave it as an exercise to the reader..." A partial answer with a little hand wave at the end is not cool.