# Rotate View/Image around specific point, not center (React Native)

Tags: react-native, math, rotation, transform, trigonometry

I'm trying to rotate a view around a certain point not the center (just like `transform-origin` in css) in React Native. At this time elements can only be rotated around the center. The result should be two views/images containing a point laying upon each other at exactly this point, while one of the views is rotated at the desired point. React Native does not support this layout feature yet, so I have to calculate the offsets and then add them using translateX and translateY.

I've tried several approaches e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165715/react-native-transforms-with-pivot-point) but I'm not getting the desired result. Reacts matrix transform is deprecated, so better not use it. I know that it has to be simple trigonometry stuff but I don't have any idea.

I think at first I need to diff the position of the point from the center of the object, then apply a angle, and then? If I use the offset calculated before applying the rotation, i don't get the rotation at the desired point.

Thanks for answers!

[here is an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0fQR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found a way and formular to calculate the offset. The desired point of rotation gets obviously rotated as well, when applying an angle to the object. So what I had to do was getting the position of this point (lets call it pRotated) by using rotationmatrices with the position of both the center (m) of the object and the desired point of rotation (p) like this:

```
angle = alpha * (Math.PI / 180)
pRotated.x = m.x + (p.x - m.x) * Math.cos(angle) - (p.y - m.y) * Math.sin(angle)
pRotated.y = m.y + (p.x - m.x) * Math.sin(angle) + (p.y - m.y) * Math.cos(angle)
```

Then it was easy to get the offset using

```
translateX = pRotated.x - p.x
translateY = pRotated.y - p.y
```

which then can just be applied to the object, and then its rotated by alpha around point p.

I've attached a [scribble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgDE3.jpg) for further explanation.

Comment: What does `p` and `m` represent?

Comment: p is point of edge and m is mid around which object is rotating

Comment: what is aplha here

Answer (score 4):

I just made a `withAnchorPoint` function to make transform working with anchor point easier in react-native. https://github.com/sueLan/react-native-anchor-point.

You can use it like this:

```js
import { withAnchorPoint } from 'react-native-anchor-point';

getTransform = () => {
    let transform = {
        transform: [{ perspective: 400 }, { rotateX: rotateValue }],
    };
    return withAnchorPoint(transform, { x: 0.5, y: 0 }, { width: CARD_WIDTH, height: CARD_HEIGHT });
};

<Animated.View style={[styles.blockBlue, this.getTransform()]} />
```

I also wrote an article for it. 
[image]