# React Native Animated Rotation Anchor Point

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated

I'm trying to get this rotation animation with an anchor point done, similar to the standard CSS attribute *transform-origin*. I've read about shifting the whole thing before the rotation like [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165715/react-native-transforms-with-pivot-point), but i can't get that to work in my case.

My element is defined like this:

```
<Animated.View
    style={[ 
       styles.test,
       { transform: [{ rotate: rotateInterpolator }] },
    ]}
>
    <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Test</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

with the following styles applied directly, since they are needed on mount:

```
test: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    height: containerHeight,
    width: containerWidth,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    transform: [{ translateX: -containerHeight / 2 }, { translateY: -containerHeight / 2 }],
},
```

I have defined my interpolator for the rotation like this:

```
const rotateInterpolator = rotateValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ["90deg", "0deg"],
});
```

On user input, i start the animation for the Animated Value `rotateValue`:

```
Animated.timing(rotateValue, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 500,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: false,
}).start();
```

But since there is no option to define the anchor point, the element will rotate around its center, which is the center of the container defined by `containerWidth` and `containerHeight`.

However I want the anchor to be at the center on the bottom of the container, which would be `(containerWidth / 2, containerHeight)`.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out after a lot of tinkering. I looked up multiple other resources and they all used the shifting like i mentioned in my question.

```
<Animated.View
    style={[ 
       styles.test,
       { transform: [
             { translateY: containerHeight / 2 }, 
             { rotate: rotateInterpolator }, 
             { translateY: -(containerHeight / 2) }
          ]
       },
    ]}
>
    <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Test</Text>
</Animated.View>
```